# TypeScript gives compile error "Object is possibly 'undefined'." but only with class variable and not scope variables

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, undefined

In TypeScript with `strict` enabled ([TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAdgVwFsAjCAJwG4picCTyqBfAWACg2BjAGwwGdeoAIQxk0bNlElQAxBgD8OeHArjWU6iIAUASjFr1UjnFy9gmZFGAALAJa8AdLLn2MK-Qag2AZlE0BCDF1UMghgfDJcChZ2dwMAejioAFEyMjgyHAB5YgArCA4zOygwOH4bYi4QKAByfFwAEwgvG1wIeur7CQ8oIxMzYgtrO0cMe2I3dWiuyWIRACYdPW6e41MoOFzB2wdpAHNQpR03aYNetYwLDZznVxP1b18AoJCwiKjVZYSoADlEcjSMndDKt+pdcmMqB4gZIznAuBB7Fw4LtNMRtBMpFNYnsDghFooEFAAD5QOqNZqtepLbovcK4UkNJotNoYyRYxhAA)):

```
type Foo = { a: number; b: number; }

class Bar {

    #a?: Foo;

    bar() {
        const a = this.#a?.a;
        if (!a) {return;}

        // Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
        const b = this.#a.b;
    }

    bar2() {
        const obj = this.#getFoo();

        const a = obj?.a;
        if (!a) {return;}

        // No error:
        const b = obj.b;       
        console.log(b);
    }

    #getFoo() : Foo | undefined {
        return undefined;
    }

}
```

Why does TS understand correctly in `bar2()` that `obj.b` cannot be `undefined`; but not `this.#a.b` in `bar()`? Is there a logic case I am missing?

In `bar()`, if I assign `const tmp = this.#a` it compiles successfully as well.

---

UPDATE: apparently it has something to do with the mutability of a variable. If I use `let obj = this.#getFoo()`, the error shows up for `obj` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ts compiler cannot guarantee that the `this.#a` value will not change between the two property accesses because TypeScript assumes that the value of a class property **can change at any time, even between two consecutive lines of code** i.e. TypeScript cannot be sure that the value of `this.#a` remains the same between the two lines.

In the `bar2()` method, the value of obj is assigned to the result of `this.#getFoo()`, which is a local variable. TypeScript can guarantee that the value of obj will not change between the two property accesses, so it does not complain.

In your last *Update*, when you use `let obj = this.#getFoo()`, TypeScript assumes that the value of obj can potentially change between the two property accesses **since it is mutable**. As a result, the error shows up for `obj` as well.

Now, to fix the issue you can assign `this.#a` to a **local constant variable**. Something like:

```js
bar() {
        const obj = this.#a; // <----Notice this
        const a = obj?.a;
        if (!a) {return;}

        // Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
        const b = obj.b;
    }
```

[TYPESCRIPT PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAdgVwFsAjCAJwG4picCTyqBfAWACg2BjAGwwGdeoAIQxk0bNlElQAxBgD8OeHArjWU6iIAUASjFr1UjnFy9gUOMQBWyKMAAWAS14A6WSv0GoRk2Yw2LlnLOGO6ekg4AZlCaAIQYuqhkEMD4ZLgULOweBgD0OVAAomRkcGQ4APJWEBxmTlBgcPwOxFwgUADk+LgAJhARDrgQ3e3OEmHeptT+Vs7EoVKZY5LEIgBMOnphXsaTATb2Tq4A5slKOu5LBhO+04HB856R0XEJSSlpGapbeVAAcojkEplS7qa5TFABWZUTwgww7OBcCDOLhwI6aYjaB5QRbZaQnYBnXSKBBQAA+UC6vX6g26mzCb1SuApPT6AyGWJxjCAA)

[Context References](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

Comment: I messed up my brain reading your example and thought I found a wrong case. Turned out you are correct 

Comment: Nothing, I thought the flow analysis was wrong so I tried out a bunch of scenarios and messed a few of them up.